# Enable Spring Security pre-post-annotations programmatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, annotations

I have Spring WebMVC Application using `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostAuthorice` annotations on the controller-methods. But these annotations are ignored since I don't have enabled it in my spring security.

If I would have a `spring-security.xml` I could enable it with the following line:

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
```

Unfortunately I have a complete Annotation-based configuration.
Spring-Security in principle works in my Application.

My question: **How can I enable pre-post-annotation with an annotation based MVC configuration?**

- Spring-Version: 4.0.5.RELEASE
- Spring-Security-Version: 3.2.4.RELEASE

This is my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` implementation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity()
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(new ShaPasswordEncoder(256))
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, enabled from user where USERNAME=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.username, r.name from user u, role r, user_has_role uhr where u.id = uhr.user_id and r.id = uhr.role_id and u.username = ?  ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                .and()
            .logout()
                //.logoutUrl("/logout") //this is the default
                // Call the URL invalidate_session after logout...
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/invalidate_session")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
               // @see http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-configure
            .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

My `MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` is empty:

```
public class MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends
        AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I had to add the following annotation to the Configuration-class: `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)`